# JavaScript in iOS that responses to programmatic calls

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm using Processing with the [HYPE framework](http://hypeframework.org/) to create some visualizations and want to put it in my iOS app. I've searched around a bit and it looks like the easiest solution would be to export Processing to JS and put that in a `UIWebView`.

The part I'm unsure about is that I need to be able to send input to the JS to adjust the visualization on a steady timer. My first thought is that I can set up key listeners in the JS, and then programmatically simulate a key press within the app. Is that possible? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Not a javascript expert but I know you can run JS in UIWebView. eg:

```
// Get
NSString *innerHTML = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];

// Set
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];
```

I hope this guides you in the right direction.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)